# How to see Browser apps under Applications in Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, directory

I have been trying to find the "official" names of my browser apps (Chrome, Brave, Safari, etc.) as I was experimenting with opening different browsers from the command line.

I was able to figure out the name for Brave (`brave\ browser`) by perusing the internet but wanted to find a better way to list out ALL of my browsers by name in the command line. I found out how to find application by cd-ing into `/System/Applications/` and then typing out `ls` like any other directory. It shows the below.

```
App Store.app       Launchpad.app       Reminders.app
Automator.app       Mail.app            Shortcuts.app
Books.app           Maps.app            Siri.app
Calculator.app      Messages.app        Stickies.app
Calendar.app        Mission Control.app Stocks.app
Chess.app           Music.app           System Preferences.app
Contacts.app        News.app            TV.app
Dictionary.app      Notes.app           TextEdit.app
FaceTime.app        Photo Booth.app     Time Machine.app
FindMy.app          Photos.app          Utilities
Font Book.app       Podcasts.app        VoiceMemos.app
Home.app            Preview.app
Image Capture.app   QuickTime Player.app
```

I am curious how I can see other apps, such as Google Chrome.app, Brave Browser.app, etc. I can see them when I go to Applications via finder but I wanted to see how I can list in the terminal.

Comment: `ps -aux | grep -Ei 'firefox|safari|chrom'` assuming an instance of the app is running.

Comment: Look in /Applications. See [this question on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434390/how-do-i-get-access-to-applications-from-the-command-line) (which is a better place for questions like this, since Stackoverflow is just about programming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@LMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2834978/lmc) and [@Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) I was able to find an elegant solution. It turns out since Catalina 10.15, Mac split up applications into two volumes:

1. /System/Applications
2. /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/

The first one basically houses all "system" applications; applications that are built in with the Mac OS. The second one houses user installed applications. It is in the second one where you can find your browsers.